# creating a json request and response for tickets based on a US region

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

I am working on a quiz and need to develop restful API to get all tickets for a region. ticket counts  are based on a US city (like a heat map) where a circle on the city shows the tickets count and size of the circle proportional to ticket count.

I also need to show the flights based on the request and transform it to be returned as a response based on the heat map.

how should be the sample json request and response?

Answer (score 1):

For get all tickets based a region:
Get method, url http://localhost/api/v1/tickets?region=us

```
[{
    "id" : 1,
    "ticketNumber" : 1001,
    "name" :  "Memo", 
    "regionId" : 2
 }, {
    "id" : 2,
    "ticketNumber" : 1002,
    "name" :  "Memo2", 
    "regionId" : 2
 }]
```

Comment: thanks, that is a good start, so the name attribute here is like name of city? what does memo signify?

Comment: Ticket name @pri_dev